# Difference between deactivating, uninstalling, and deleting plugins

Tags: plugins, wp-cli

I understand the difference between deactivation and uninstallation. But the CLI also has a delete option.

How does it differ?

To be safe, should I deactivate, then uninstall, then delete?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the docs about `wp plugin delete`:

> Deletes plugin files without deactivating or uninstalling.

so after runing the comand on a plugin I would expect the admin plugin page showing the warning about the missing plugin being deactivated and all the uninstalling database related actions have not taken place.

Just run uninstall with the `--deactivate` option and you are done.

https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/plugin/delete

https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/plugin/uninstall/

Comment: Or equivalently, `deactivate --uninstall`